risk of keeping efficient implementation details a trade secret
The invention is in the field of software development. In particular, it is in the consumer app space.
For the invention to be practical enough to be a consumer app on the market, it must have some level of efficiency.
Strategy:

Described just enough details in the patent application for ennoblement.
Keep efficient method that enables the invention to be practical out of the patent and as a trade secret.

Questions:

Do I risk someone patenting the efficient method?
Can the efficient method, which involves the standard use of indexing database tables,  horizontal sharding of hardware, etc. actually be patented if someone were to try?


In my opinion it is an unethical strategy that any registered practitioner working with you should decline to participate in.
Without full details it is not possible to say if an improved method of carrying out your invention would be patentable. It is was patented by someone else, they would need a license from you since their method infringes your more general claims and you would need a license from them to use their patented specific method.

I think prior use rights may possibly apply in such a scenario to prevent the need for OP to license, if OP was practicing the improved method as a trade secret backend software earlier than the "someone else" filed.

Prior use rights are intended for manufacturing methods. (a) In General.—A person shall be entitled to a defense under section 282(b) with respect to subject matter consisting of a process, or consisting of a machine, manufacture, or composition of matter used in a manufacturing or other commercial process, that would otherwise infringe a claimed invention being asserted against the person if—

The snippet you posted clearly says "or other commercial process". I am hardly an expert in this branch of legalese, but there are at least some blog posts indicating that it would apply to all processes post-AIA: https://www.finnegan.com/en/insights/blogs/at-the-ptab-blog/the-new-prior-user-rights-defense-how-often-will-it-be-asserted.html


Described just enough details in the patent application for ennoblement.

Pre-AIA this would have been a no-no; it was an obligation that the "best mode" known to the inventor be described. Now patents can no longer be invalidated for failing to disclose the best mode. It is still technically a requirement during examination, but in practice the Examiner has no way to know that you are holding back the best mode (unless you have disclosed it elsewhere than your patent application). Since there is no consequence once the patent passes examination, the practice of withholding the best mode has essentially been legalized, though it remains controversial and a "dodgy" thing to do.
IMHO the policy behind removing this requirement is sound. Suppose one invents a new algorithm that one wants to patent, but during proving the design one also discovers a particularly efficient software implementation. Pre-AIA one would have to disclose the clever bits of the software implementation as part of the patent; post-AIA one can keep the latter as a trade secret.

Can the efficient method, which involves the standard use of indexing database tables, horizontal sharding of hardware, etc. actually be patented if someone were to try?

If these are relatively standard techniques, what is the point of attempting to keep them secret? If it is the case that a person of ordinary skill can easily recreate the efficient embodiment given the inefficient one, then one is better off including it in the patent and having some claims to it.

I think you have an unintended double negative in the first sentence.  I don’t think the law was changed to encourage hiding the ball but it does remove uncertainty in arguments about what mode is “best” under what criteria. Since it is still a rule, even with no teeth for the applicant, I believe it is unethical for a practitioner to file something they know violates it.

Fixed the double negative, thanks. I see your point about the ethicality of it from the standpoint of a practitioner.
